# Combining Rows in SELECT Case Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join, case

I have this query

```
SELECT questions.question_id, 
       questions.question, 
       questions.answer_id, 
       nlp_terms.word,
       ( CASE 
           WHEN answers.id = questions.answer_id THEN answers.answer 
         END ) AS answer, 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN answers.id != questions.answer_id THEN answers.answer 
         END ) AS incorrect_answer_1, 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN answers.id != questions.answer_id THEN answers.answer 
         END ) AS incorrect_answer_2 
FROM   questions 
       JOIN answers 
         ON answers.question_id = questions.question_id 
       JOIN nlp_terms 
         ON questions.question_id = nlp_terms.question_id
WHERE questions.question_id = '1'
```

This query outputs:

```
╔═════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦════════╦════════════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ question_id ║                 question                  ║ answer_id ║   word    ║ answer ║ incorrect_answer_1 ║ incorrect_answer_2 ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬════════╬════════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ What      ║ NULL   ║ South America      ║ South America      ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ continent ║ NULL   ║ South America      ║ South America      ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ is        ║ NULL   ║ South America      ║ South America      ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ the       ║ NULL   ║ South America      ║ South America      ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ country   ║ NULL   ║ South America      ║ South America      ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ Lesotho   ║ NULL   ║ South America      ║ South America      ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ in?       ║ NULL   ║ South America      ║ South America      ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ What      ║ Africa ║ NULL               ║ NULL               ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ continent ║ Africa ║ NULL               ║ NULL               ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ is        ║ Africa ║ NULL               ║ NULL               ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ the       ║ Africa ║ NULL               ║ NULL               ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ country   ║ Africa ║ NULL               ║ NULL               ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ Lesotho   ║ Africa ║ NULL               ║ NULL               ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ in?       ║ Africa ║ NULL               ║ NULL               ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ What      ║ NULL   ║ Australia          ║ Australia          ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ continent ║ NULL   ║ Australia          ║ Australia          ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ is        ║ NULL   ║ Australia          ║ Australia          ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ the       ║ NULL   ║ Australia          ║ AustraliA          ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ country   ║ NULL   ║ Australia          ║ Australia          ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ Lesotho   ║ NULL   ║ Australia          ║ Australia          ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ in?       ║ NULL   ║ Australia          ║ Australia          ║
╚═════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩════════╩════════════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

As you can see it is bringing in all the data I want, it's just that my CASE statements are taking a row of their own instead of being grouped.

I've numerous `GROUP BY` operations but cannot get it to be like my expected output:

```
╔═════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦════════╦════════════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ question_id ║                 question                  ║ answer_id ║   word    ║ answer ║ incorrect_answer_1 ║ incorrect_answer_2 ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬════════╬════════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ What      ║ Africa ║ South America      ║ Australia          ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ continent ║ Africa ║ South America      ║ Australia          ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ is        ║ Africa ║ South America      ║ Australia          ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ the       ║ Africa ║ South America      ║ Australia          ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ country   ║ Africa ║ South America      ║ Australia          ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ Lesotho   ║ Africa ║ South America      ║ Australia          ║
║        1369 ║ What continent is the country Lesotho in? ║      4106 ║ in?       ║ Africa ║ South America      ║ Australia          ║
╚═════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩════════╩════════════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

What am I missing to get my expected output?

Comment: Do all your questions only have 3 answers?

Comment: For now, yes all questions have 3 answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this produces your desired results:

```
SELECT q.question_id, q.question, q.answer_id, t.word,
       MAX(CASE WHEN a.id = q.answer_id THEN a.answer 
           END) AS answer, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN a.id <> q.answer_id THEN a.answer 
           END) AS incorrect_answer_1, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN a.id <> q.answer_id THEN a.answer 
           END) AS incorrect_answer_2 
FROM questions q JOIN
     answers a
     ON a.question_id = q.question_id JOIN
     nlp_terms t
     ON q.question_id = t.question_id
WHERE q.question_id = 1
GROUP BY q.question_id, q.question, q.answer_id, t.word;
```

Comment: Yes! Love you thanks. Made edit `MIN(CASE WHEN q.id` should be `MIN(CASE WHEN q.question_id`

Comment: Assuming I must bring in `nlp_terms.id` auto_increment (`t.id`) to ensure the words are in the correct order as well? Works fine when I add it, as the answer query above is sorting by `t.word` alphabetically

Comment: You actually spotted it before me (I mean not surprising :) but I hadn't re-read the entire update to notice)-- looking more into it the `MIN(CASE` I previously commented on should not reference table q at all, and in fact should be `a.id` to `q.question_id` in all the `CASE` statements. And as stated just the above query with a an included `GROUP BY` `t.id` and ending the query with `ORDER` by `t.id` output works perfectly. Thank you again for sharing your knowledge and insights on this I am getting better and you have helped me before I remember.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "WHERE questions.question_id = '1' AND answer IS NOT NULL"

reference: http://www.dofactory.com/sql/where-isnull

Comment: Same result. Thanks though.